# Redirect url to Seo friendly url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ product-detail.php?asin=$1 [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product-detail.php?asin=[^&]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to redirect url to create seo friendly url like http://example.com/asinvaluecomesherewhichisuniqueinthedatabase

my sql query looks like this

```
if (isset($_GET['asin'])) {
    $Product_asin = $_GET['asin'];

    $product_query = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `Asin` =  '$Product_asin' ";
```

The link looks like

```
<a href="/fashe-colorlib/product-detail.php?asin=<?php echo $cat_Asin; ?>" </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/fashe-colorlib/product-detail.php?asin=<?php echo $cat_Asin; ?>" </a>


RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ product-detail.php?asin=$1 [L,NC]
```

I had to remove the following part of the link.

```
product-detail.php?asin=
```

Now the working link looks like :

```
<a href="/fashe-colorlib/<?php echo $cat_Asin; ?>" </a>
```

I also got rid of this part :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product-detail.php?asin=[^&]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

It was suggested on another post , here on stack.

Finally, i am able to get

```
http://example.com/xxxxx
```

From

```
http://example.com/product-detail.php?asin=xxxxx
```